# ffmpeg conversion for an entire folder?

Tags: ffmpeg, directory

Ive been using:

```
sudo ffmpeg -i Test.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac -ac 2 -ab 328k Test.mp4
```

for individual files, but now I have many gigabytes of mkvs in a folder and would like to do a conversion for all at once and walk away from the computer.  I appologize for my ignorance, but i am very new to linux and i dont understand how bash scripts are written or if it would even be necessary.

also, i believe the command downsamples the DTS audio in the mkv to 2 channel AAC.  am i correct that 328k is the highest bitrate I can convert to?

Comment: Why are you using sudo? There should be no need to run video encoding with root privileges.

Comment: hell, i dont know.  i guess to keep from having to type the commands out again and wasting more time if it says you dont have privileges to do a command.

Comment: You really don't have to type the command again. You just push the up arrow, press home and prepend the sudo. But thats only required when you are making changes to the system. Not for general work.

Comment: The easiest way to run the previous command with `sudo` is to simply type `sudo !!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, this assumes at least one MKV file in the folder.

```sh
for INF in *.mkv
do
  ffmpeg -i "$INF" -c:v copy -c:a libfaac -ac 2 -ab 328k "${INF%.*}.mp4"
done
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response.  again im very new at this, would i make a file called something.sh with that text in it, then make it executable with chmod +x?

Comment: @user218314 Yes, you could do that. Any specific problems doing so?

Comment: no, i figured it out.  thank you so much for your help, i never would have been able to put that together on my own.